# Adding a current month flag

Tags: sql, teradata

I need some help framing the following logic..

I have a date master table (past and future dates). I need to add a flag only next to those dates that are in the current month.. This part is easy enough i can add a column that converts all dates to the first of month (ex. 1/1/2000, 1/2/2000, 1/3/2000 would all fall under 1/1/2000) and compare it to the same calculation for the system's current_date. If true add flag = 'Y'

Where it gets tricky is if the date is a saturday or sunday, current month should point to the previous date. Ex if current date is 2/1/2018 and it falls on a Saturday.. January should still be flagged as the current month until Feb 3rd. Trying to get this piece figured out.

Any suggestions? THanks

Answer (score 0):

A simple method is to use `date_trunc()`:

```
select (case when trunc(datecol, 'M') = trunc(current_date, 'M')
             then 1 else 0
        end) as flag
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Trunc(calendar_date
      - CASE day_of_week -- based on Teradata's syscalendar, week starts on sunday
          WHEN 1 THEN 2  -- sunday   = 7 in ISO calendar
          WHEN 7 THEN 1  -- saturday = 6 in ISO calendar
          ELSE 0
        END, 'mon') as First_of_Business_Month
```